# How to create a file and make it downloadable in GWT?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I want to export the data in a celltable to a CSV file. I understand this must be done in the server side. I'm a bit lost on how to create a file, write the lines and then make the client download it.

One it's served, it could be downloaded automatically or by a "Download" button, is the same.

Comment: i did it in my code. when download button click, it will generate a file and let user download it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to generate file and serve it directly you can create a servlet and hit the servlet url in a Window, You may want to take the same datasource and use it at the server side to convert it into a csv. Please follow along the steps as described in ([Download a generated pdf from client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16376924/download-a-generated-pdf-from-client)) and for downloading that from GWT Window follow  ([How to download a file via a button click i GWT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684666/how-to-download-a-file-via-a-button-click-i-gwt)),